# How to import a variable from a Pytest funtion to another Python script file?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I have the below Pytest script `Webtest.py` where my url to be tested is defined.

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class Test_main():

    @pytest.fixture()
    def test_setup(self):

        # initiating browser
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"drivers/chromedriver v86/chromedriver.exe",options=chrome_options)

        yield
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()
        print("Test Completed")

    def test_case01(self,test_setup):
        self.url='lifesciences.cactusglobal.com'
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        title=self.driver.title
        print(title)
```

I want to use the `self.url` value from the above script to be used in another python script `SSL_trial.py`. I tried it like below, but was showing error even before execution.

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
import idna
from Test_Website_Security import Test_main  #imported the file which is saved in the same folder
url_here= Test_main.test_case02().url  #I tried to call the variable here

from socket import socket
from collections import namedtuple

HostInfo = namedtuple(field_names='cert hostname peername', typename='HostInfo')

HOSTS = [
    (url_here, 443)
]

def verify_cert(cert, hostname):
   cert.has_expired()

def get_certificate(hostname, port):
    hostname_idna = idna.encode(hostname)
    sock = socket()

    sock.connect((hostname, port))
    peername = sock.getpeername()
    ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD) 
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = SSL.VERIFY_NONE

    sock_ssl = SSL.Connection(ctx, sock)
    sock_ssl.set_connect_state()
    sock_ssl.set_tlsext_host_name(hostname_idna)
    sock_ssl.do_handshake()
    cert = sock_ssl.get_peer_certificate()
    crypto_cert = cert.to_cryptography()
    sock_ssl.close()
    sock.close()

    return HostInfo(cert=crypto_cert, peername=peername, hostname=hostname)

def get_alt_names(cert):
    try:
        ext = cert.extensions.get_extension_for_class(x509.SubjectAlternativeName)
        return ext.value.get_values_for_type(x509.DNSName)
    except x509.ExtensionNotFound:
        return None

def get_common_name(cert):
    try:
        names = cert.subject.get_attributes_for_oid(NameOID.COMMON_NAME)
        return names[0].value
    except x509.ExtensionNotFound:
        return None

def get_issuer(cert):
    try:
        names = cert.issuer.get_attributes_for_oid(NameOID.COMMON_NAME)
        return names[0].value
    except x509.ExtensionNotFound:
        return None


def print_basic_info(hostinfo):
    s = '''» {hostname} « … {peername}
    \tcommonName: {commonname}
    \tSAN: {SAN}
    \tissuer: {issuer}
    \tnotBefore: {notbefore}
    \tnotAfter:  {notafter}
    '''.format(
            hostname=hostinfo.hostname,
            peername=hostinfo.peername,
            commonname=get_common_name(hostinfo.cert),
            SAN=get_alt_names(hostinfo.cert),
            issuer=get_issuer(hostinfo.cert),
            notbefore=hostinfo.cert.not_valid_before,
            notafter=hostinfo.cert.not_valid_after
    )
    print(s)
    print(type(s))
    xyz=list(s.split("\t"))
    print(xyz)
    print(len(xyz))
    print(xyz[5])
    print(xyz[4])

def check_it_out(hostname, port):
    hostinfo = get_certificate(hostname, port)
    print_basic_info(hostinfo)


import concurrent.futures
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as e:
        for hostinfo in e.map(lambda x: get_certificate(x[0], x[1]), HOSTS):
            print_basic_info(hostinfo)
```

I am not sure how to do it. I know its quite basic but any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If a link is a constant and you cam do this test for multiple IP's, I recommend you using a parametrized test (which will create 'n' amount of tests for each case (for example for 5 websites it will generate 5 tests)). If you are asking about accession, if I recall correctly, you can create a fixture for it (which will be just a get call) and the  you can call and use it freely, you can even put it as a prameter if you want it to do something before the method is executed (I have not played exactly with this type of problem but it should work in my opinion) ~ Good Luck

Comment: Would it make sense for you to define the URL in a configuration file (text or json) and always load the URL from there instead?

Answer (score 0):

if `test_case01` somehow can retun `self.url` then probaly you can try the below solution :-

let's say `A.py` looks something like this :-

```
def test_case01():
    url = 'lifesciences.cactusglobal.com'
    return url
```

and if you want to use url from `test_case01` into `B.py` :-

you can probably do something like this :

```
from A import *

var = test_case01()
print(var)
```

Comment: My first script has a function `def test_case01(self)`. I tried your suggestion but for `B.py` I get an error: missing parameter in the function called at `var = test_case01()`. What do I fill in the parameter? Tried `self`, I get an error undefined parameter.

Comment: in your first script `test_case01(self,test_setup):` :- this means when you are calling this in second script, you need to pass those arguments as well

Comment: I did that in the second script. But I get this error: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`